# Casting void pointer

Tags: pointers, struct, casting

I have a struct

```
struct GROUP_POINTS
{
   unsigned char number_of_points;
   void *points;
};

struct GROUP_POINTS group_points;
```

The reason for points being a void pointer is that I want to keep the groups as general as possible, and setting the "link" to the correct struct at runtime.

One of the other structs is:

```
struct POINT_A
{
   unsigned char something;
};
```

I can make another pointer that points to the *points to get access to the struct like :

```
struct POINT_A *point_a = (struct POINT_A *)group_points.points;
```

and then access the points by doing :

```
(*point_a).number_of_points = 5;
```

But I would really like to be able to use it like this:

```
group_points.points.number_of_points
```

So not needing the second pointer just to point to the void pointer. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Is it C or C++? Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the language is C++, you may want to consider template solution like that:

```
template <class T>
struct GROUP_POINTS
{
   unsigned char number_of_points;
   T *points;
};

typedef GROUP_POINTS<unsigned char> POINT_A;
//another typedefs for another points.
```

Also, you probably would be fine with just `std::vector<T>` instead of whole points structs, but just to illustrate general approach this is how it can be done.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to add programming language, but it is C, do std::vector will not compute :) thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since all you need is to avoid using another pointer, you can use it like this:

```
((struct POINT_A *)group_points).points.number_of_points = 5;
```

Note that the type cast has a lower precedence than that of the `.` operator, the parenthesis is necessary.

Comment: This has to be done for each access right ? There isn't any way to cast the void pointer so I can just do group_points.points.number.... in the rest of the code ?

Comment: @user1244472 You can't. Because a type cast won't change the type of the original variable. For instance, `int a = 42; double b = (double)a;` but the type of `a` is still `int`.

Comment: Understood, that's what I thought but did not hope for :) Well thanks for all the help guys!